# Remove Win 10 password - not required but forgotten

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

My dad's laptop apparently has a password for Windows 10 but he doesn't need to enter it on start up - the password screen flashes by briefly with it already filled in. However, while trying to change the display settings recently, the desktop goes off for a moment, then comes back to the login screen, waiting for the password, which has long been forgotten, since it's never used. We can get past it by shutting down from the login screen and starting up again. How can we remove this password if we don't know it?

Comment: is it a local account or a microsoft account?

Comment: It's a local account

Comment: try the Create a New User to Save Account Files described at https://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/ and then use the new administrator account to change the password from you father's account. Had to do it 2 years ago on my mother's laptop and worked perfect.